Binomial distribution in R is not symmetrical
I expected the code below to produce the same output, but it's not. My thought was based on the the binomial distributon formula for the density function. I use Rstudio.
Where is the mistake?
$$
P(x) = \binom{n}{x} p^xp^{n-x}
$$
r12 = pbinom(2,5,(pnorm(1.4)))
r13 = pbinom(3,5,(1-pnorm(1.4)))


I guess you didn't write the pmf correctly.

Sure it is, in the sense that you can flip the argument to the pmf end for end and take the complement of the probability parameter. For example, just compare these dbinom(0:5,5,pnorm(1.4)); dbinom(5:0,5,1-pnorm(1.4)). But when you sum them (as with pbinom) you have to sum the corresponding terms.

Ah, you are right. There are 2 formulas and I confused pmf with cdf, If I apply the correct one, the results are equal
